# Stored procedure as view or calling in function

Tags: t-sql, function, stored-procedures, view

Can I a stored procedure to induce a systemic view? For example I have it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.status_serwer
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp
END
```

Sysmail_help_status procedure returns the status of the server: 'stopped' or 'started' And now, can I call start_serwer procedure as a view or in a function? Someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look inside that stored proc, you can just grab the query that it runs and modify it a little so you can use it elsewhere, like this;

```
SELECT 
    CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msdb.sys.service_queues WHERE name = N'ExternalMailQueue' AND is_receive_enabled = 1) 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'STOPPED' 
        ELSE 'STARTED' 
        END AS 'sysmail_status'
```

Here's the original for reference:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sysmail_help_status_sp]
  WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WHERE name = N'ExternalMailQueue' AND is_receive_enabled = 1)
       SELECT 'STOPPED' AS Status
    ELSE
       SELECT 'STARTED' AS Status
END
```

Comment: Hmmm it is good idea, but when I execute this code I always receive 'stopped' when databasemail is 'started', because T check it by procedure sysmail_status_help_sp.

Comment: So the stored proc says "Started" but the query I gave says stopped?  It works fine for me. What does running this give you?

SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WHERE name = N'ExternalMailQueue' AND is_receive_enabled = 1

Comment: My mistake, sys.service_queues should be msdb.sys.service_queues.  I updated my post.  Try running it now.